# How to allow only numbers in a variable?

Tags: c++, io, numbers, iostream, cin

I am having some problems with my code, here is a part of the code I am having problem with.

Point of this code is that if a user enters something that is not a number, for example a character `p`, program should ask user to enter again, this part works.

If user enters a combination of numbers and characters program should ask user to enter again. For example `n12` or `12n` are not valid.

Part where a character comes first, like `n12` doesn't cause problems, but the problem comes where a number is first and something else second, like `12n`,  which is not valid, but my code prints out the number `12` and later says that number is not valid.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int n;

    while(1)
    {

        cout<<"Enter a number, 0 for exit: ";
        cin>>n;

        if(!cin)
        {
            cout<<"You didnt enter a valid number\n";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(1000,'\n');
            continue;
        }
        cout<<"Number is: "<<n<<endl;

        if(n==0) return 0;
    }
}
```

Examples of output of the code:

1°

```
Enter a number, 0 for exit: 12
Number is: 12
```

2°

```
Enter a number, 0 for exit: n
You didnt enter valid number
```

3°

```
Enter a number, 0 for exit: n12
You didnt enter valid number
```

4° <--- this one does not work properly

```
Enter a number, 0 for exit: 12n
Number is: 12
Enter a number, 0 for exit: You didnt enter valid number
```

Edit: if it's possible, I'd like to solve this problem without including additional libraries.

Comment: After `cin >> n;` you could do a `getline` and then check whether that was an empty string

Comment: This is not a "problem", but a well-defined behavior of `cin`..

Comment: @nbro: Which might still be a problem if you don't know how to achive the desired otherwise.

Comment: @derM Indeed, that's why I edited my comment to surround the word problem with quotes.

Comment: Hi, if its possible I'd like to solve this using only functions from <iostream>

Comment: That's a tricky requirement. `std::stoi` makes this almost easy, but with only iostream your best bet is `std::getline` to read a `std::string` and... Crap. No `std::string` if all you get is iostream.

Comment: The iostream library was never intended to be used for writing interactive programs, so really you cannot come up with something completely bullet-proof. If you want to atempt it, you need to read the raw input into a string, and then parse it with an istringstream, but it will never be completely satisfactory.

Comment: OK. new plan. Read all of the characters one by one until you hit EOL and try to convert to a digit. If not a digit, bad. If to many digits to fit into an `int`, bad.

Comment: Hi, I just done a bit googling, and looks like adding cin.peek()!='\n' to the if statement solves the problem, so the new if is: if(!cin || cin.peek()!='\n') now the thing is, i don't understand what this does, can anyone explain please?

Comment: @noobcoder have you considered accepting an answer, if your problem is solved of course, so that the question is marked as resolved?

Answer (score 4):

You could use [isdigit()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/), [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) and [std::all_of()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/all_of/) from additional standard libraries (which is okay, not an overkill), like this (you store the input in the string and then you check if for every character of that string the isdigit function succeeds, which means that the input is purely numerically in that case):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str;
    std::cin >> str;
    (std::all_of(str.begin(), str.end(), [] (char c) { return isdigit(c); })) ? std::cout << "It's a number!\n" : std::cout << "isdigit() failed\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ g++ -Wall -std=c++0x main.cpp 
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ ./a.out 
4
It's a number!
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ ./a.out 
f
isdigit() failed
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ ./a.out 
12n
isdigit() failed
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the whole line that the user entered, not just part of it.  `istream::operator>>` stops reading when it encounters a character that does not belong to the data type currently being read.  That is why input like `12n` gets processed as `12` and `n` separately.

You are not going to solve this using just `<iostream>` functionality alone.  This is best handled using things like `std::getline()` and `std::stoi()`/`std::strtol()`, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool to_int(const string &str, int &i)
{
    size_t pos;
    i = stoi(str, &pos);
    return (str.c_str()[pos] == '\0');
}

int main ()
{
    string line;
    int n;

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter a number, 0 for exit: ";
        getline(cin, line);

        if (!to_int(line, n))
        {
            cout << "You didn't enter a valid number\n";
            continue;
        }

        cout << "Number is: " << n << endl;

        if (n == 0) break;
    }
    while (1);

    return 0;
}
```

If you don't want to use a conversion function like `std::stoi()`, at least use a `std::istringstream` instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

bool to_int(const string &str, int &i)
{
    char c;
    istringstream iss(str);
    iss >> i;
    return !(iss.fail() || iss.get(c));
}

int main ()
{
    string line;
    int n;

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter a number, 0 for exit: ";
        getline(cin, line);

        if (!to_int(line, n))
        {
            cout << "You didn't enter a valid number\n";
            continue;
        }

        cout << "Number is: " << n << endl;

        if (n == 0) break;
    }
    while (1);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the number, if it has something other than a digit, print "You didnt enter valid number", else print the number. We will be getting input as a string and using ctype.h to verify if the string's character it is a digit:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string n;
    bool is_valid = true;

    while (1)
    {

        cout << "Enter a number, 0 for exit: ";
        cin >> n;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n.length(); i++) {

            if (!isdigit(n[i])) {
                cout << "You didnt enter a valid number\n";
                is_valid = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (is_valid) cout << "Number is: " << n << endl;

        if (n == "0") return 0;
    }
}
```